# May a hashtable store its keys in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have learned multiple languages,  but It is the first time I have realized that some C++ books implements its HashTables without storing the key, only the value. I understand that due design specifications it is valid but I still have the question.

Is mandatory for a C++ hashtable to be implemented to only store values ?

#### Edit:

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954525/print-a-hash-table-functionit-does-not-work-and-the-program-it-crashes/60955127?noredirect=1#comment107841691_60955127)

And this book: M. Weiss Allen, Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++. Addison-Wesley, 2014. pag 197.

Comment: Where did you come across hash tables that don't store keys? What C++ books are these? That doesn't sound right. Could you share a quote? I suspect you've misunderstood them.

Comment: Reading the linked question and answer, I do not see how you could come up with the idea that they were talking about a hash table that does not store a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described are 2 different kinds of tables.
One is a list, the other is a key-value-pair.

They hash tables you are familiar with are [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) in the standard library.
The other one is an [unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). They have difference use-cases.
Certainly, since both use hash functions, both can be called hash tables.

Comment: Note: An unordered set is usually the reverse: a hash table that stores *only* keys, no values.